# Завершение ввода символом

Tags: c

Мне нужно закончить ввод символом 0, я проверяю значение, которое ввожу с клавиатуры через getchar(), но почему то когда пользователь вводит 0, программа просто заканчивает работу, хотя после этого должна напечататься таблица. Не могу понять в чем дело.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 10

typedef struct
{
    int number;
    double x1, y1;
    double x2, y2;
    double sq;
}coord;

coord rectang[MAX]; //масив структур

int Enter(int);
void Print(void);

int size = Enter(MAX); //фактична кількість елементів масиву

void main(void)
{
    Print();
}

int Enter(int k)
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    int m = 0;
    int end = 1;
    printf(" 0 - завершити введення\n");
    for (m; m < k; m++) {
        rectang[m].number = m + 1;
        printf(" Прямокутник №%d\n", rectang[m].number);
        printf(" Введіть координати верхньої лівої вершини:\n x1: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &rectang[m].x1);
        printf(" y1: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &rectang[m].y1);
        printf(" Введіть координати нижньої правої вершини:\n x2: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &rectang[m].x2);
        printf(" y2: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &rectang[m].y2);
        rewind(stdin);
        if ((end = getchar()) == '0')
            break;
    }
    return m;
}

void Print(void)
{
    int m = 0;
    printf("\n Таблиця введених даних:");
    printf("\n -------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n |    №    |   ");
    printf("   x1     |   ");
    printf("   y1     |   ");
    printf("   x2     |   ");
    printf("   y2     |");
    for (m; m <= size; m++) {
        printf("\n -------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n |    %d.   |   ", rectang[m].number);
        printf(" %-9.2lf|   ", rectang[m].x1);
        printf(" %-9.2lf|   ", rectang[m].y1);
        printf(" %-9.2lf|   ", rectang[m].x2);
        printf(" %-9.2lf|", rectang[m].y2);
    }
    printf("\n -------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: И что, в чистом C скомпилировалось `int size = Enter(MAX);`?

Comment: Да, а эта форма записи неверна?

Comment: А вы скомпилируйте не как С++, а как С. Именно как С.

Comment: Я работаю в Visual C++, не могу как С скомпилировать. А как лучше сделать? И в чем ошибка?((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы не вызываете функцию Enter в функции main. Это ошибка.
2. У вас не срабатывает getchar()
3. Вы слишком увлекаетесь глобальными переменными. Ну хоть size можно же передать в Print

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #define MAX 10

   typedef struct
   {
   int number;
   double x1, y1;
   double x2, y2;
   double sq;
   }coord;

   coord rectang[MAX]; //масив структур

   int Enter(int);
   void Print(void);

   int size; 

   void main(void)
    {
      system("chcp 1251");
      size = Enter(MAX); //фактична кількість елементів масиву
      Print();
      system("pause");
    }

   int Enter(int k)
    {

       int m = 0;
       int end = 1;
       printf(" 0 - завершити введення\n");
       for (m; m < k; m++) {
         rectang[m].number = m + 1;

         printf(" Прямокутник №%d\n", rectang[m].number);
         printf(" Введіть координати верхньої лівої вершини:\n x1: ");
         scanf("%lf", &rectang[m].x1);
         printf(" y1: ");
         scanf("%lf", &rectang[m].y1);
         printf(" Введіть координати нижньої правої вершини:\n x2: ");
         scanf("%lf", &rectang[m].x2);
         printf(" y2: ");
         scanf("%lf", &rectang[m].y2);

         printf(" 1 - продолжить\n0 - завершити введення\n");
         scanf("%d",&end);
         if (end == 0)
             break;
         }
         return m;
    }



    void Print(void)
   {
       int m = 0;
       printf("\n Таблиця введених даних:");
       printf("\n -------------------------------------------------------------------");
       printf("\n |    №    |   ");
       printf("   x1     |   ");
       printf("   y1     |   ");
       printf("   x2     |   ");
       printf("   y2     |");
       for (m; m <= size; m++) {
           printf("\n -------------------------------------------------------------------");
           printf("\n |    %d.   |   ", rectang[m].number);
           printf(" %-9.2lf|   ", rectang[m].x1);
           printf(" %-9.2lf|   ", rectang[m].y1);
           printf(" %-9.2lf|   ", rectang[m].x2);
           printf(" %-9.2lf|", rectang[m].y2);
       }
       printf("\n -------------------------------------------------------------------");
   }
   ```

Comment: Да, мне кажется лучше всего size сделать локальной в main, но в задании нужно чтобы эта переменная была именно глобальной. Возможно коректно так сделать?

Comment: @Nastya объявить глобальной, а функцию вызвать в main. Исправил.

Comment: Исправила, но все равно почему то окно закрывается после ввода 0

Comment: Так и должно быть. Выполнение программы завершено и окно закрывается. Добавил system("PAUSE"); в main.

Comment: Но разве не должна после функции ввода выполняться функция Print, которую я вызываю в main после Enter? Мне же нужно еще таблицу распечатать после ввода

Comment: @Nastya функция Print выполняется. После чего окно закрывается и вы не успеваете увидеть. Поставьте задержку экрана, например  system("pause");